# How To Use BitPay

Tags: transactions, exchanges, trading, bitpay, merchants

We have a online computer company written in PHP

www.cworld.com.au

A sister site we have uses Magento

How can we use BitPay to enable our site for BTC..Is there an API

Can we get paid for every tx etc ?

Will we have a mechant BTC address?

What are some of the reversal process's..will this be a seperate new transaction

Comment: For the time being I can tell you that you can hire me to help you with everything regarding setup and Bitcoin payments ;). Later when I have more time I will try to give you a proper answer.

Comment: I think you mean [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) - as far as I know there is no BitPay plugin for the [Brotherhood of Evil Mutants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotherhood_of_Mutants) or [their leader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto_(comics)) ;)

Comment: BitPay I think needs a plug in for BOEM ...the BTC world certainly feels like it needs some super mutants fighting for the forces of good :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitPay provides a plugin for Magento, as well as [a description on how to use their plugins](https://bitpay.com/help-cart-plugins) (link requires login). One would need to setup a merchant account with the company, but it is easy and straightforward. One can specify [a Bitcoin address to withdraw the money with](https://bitpay.com/accounting) (login as above), or possibly use standard bank transfer options.

When in doubt, you best consult someone directly about your setup. Bitcoin can be a tricky system where your money can evaporate quickly. [I am available](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/323/thepiachu) if you need some professional help.

Comment: "Where your money can evaporate quickly" we should put that on the promotional brochure...lol

Answer (score 1):

Bitpay just released a new plugin for Magento which can be installed via Magento connect. The code and instructions for use are available on [github](https://github.com/bitpay/magento-plugin).